# Regex for Domains having three dots ex:- "gov.ac.in"

Tags: php, regex

We a list of URL's in this format (`http://www.xyz.gov.ac.in`). Not all of them look like this, some of them have normal domains. I am confused on how to get the domain name from a 3 dotted url. The code we have is working fine for 2 dotted domain names.
Here is the code we have:

```
function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}

echo get_domain($url) ;
```

How can we modify the above code to accommodate for 3 dotted domains as well as the other types?

The echo results should be in this format `xyz.gov.ac.in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/(^[\w|-]+\.)(?P<domain>([\w|-]+\.)+(\w+))/i
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: if we the url is http://www.octave-global.com , then it will not work. please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can't. At least not without a lookup table that has all "TLDs".

For example, in my country (The Netherlands) we have `.nl` and `.co.nl`. But `www.gov.nl` is a normal website (I'm trying to illustrate that you can't automatically say that `gov.` isn't a domain). And `www.edu.nl` doesn't exist.

Any standard regex that would try to parse them would tell you that the domain is `www.gov.nl`, while the domain is actually `gov.nl`. Same for `edu.nl`.

The only way you can accomplish what you want is by getting a list of all TLDs (and sub-TLDs) and using that to parse them.

I believe that Firefox and Chrome have such a list implemented (for coloring the domain name in the URL) and constantly keep it up-to-date. Maybe look in those sources?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this Regex instead

```
/(?P<domain>([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.)+[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i
```

Comment: It allows the Subdomain. like if URl is http://forum.xyz.com.uj.xa/adsfasdf.lkj  ... It's returning forum.xyz.com.uj.xa instead of xyz.com.uj.xa